# use next('route') and get 'undefined' response in next route in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/user/:uid', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.params.uid === 'lai9fox') next('route')
  else next()
}, (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(`<h1>hello, ${req.params.uid}</h1>`)
})

app.get('/user/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(`<h1>Welcome you, ${req.params.uid} !</h1>`)
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server is running at port 3000...'))
```

When I visit `http://localhost:3000/user/lai`, it correctly shows:

> hello, lai

But when I visit `http://localhost:3000/user/lai9fox`, it shows:

> Welcome you, undefined!

What's go wrong?

Comment: You have a typo inside the path (`:id` vs `:uid`). Instead of `req.params.uid` in the 2nd use `req.params.id` and it should be fine.

Comment: i got it, thanks bro, i am so sloppy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change the **req.params.uid** for id

```
app.get('/user/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(`<h1>Welcome you, ${req.params.id} !</h1>`)
})
```

Comment: thanks for notice, I'm too sloppy